# Access class data in second screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a user class that I pass to a second screen upon login. When I debug it the values are there on the second screen but I cant access user.firstName for some reason.

I'm getting an error on "String userFirstName = user.firstName;" the error is saying "only static members can be accessed in initilizers" Im new to flutter so im sure im doing something incorrectly.

Here is the offending code:

```
class HomeMember extends StatelessWidget {

final User user;


 formatDate(){
  var date =DateTime.now();
  var suffix = "th";
  var digit = DateTime.now().day % 10;
 if ((digit > 0 && digit < 4) && (date.day < 11 || date.day > 13)) {
suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][digit - 1];
 }
  return new DateFormat("EEEE MMMM d'$suffix'").format(DateTime.now());
 }

 HomeMember({Key key, @required this.user}) : super(key: key);

String userFirstName = user.firstName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new LBAppBar().getAppBar(),
      drawer: new LBDrawer().getDrawer(),
     body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0), Colors.grey],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight
        )
    ),
     child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,    
      children:[
        Row(
                children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right:30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[



                Text("Hi $userFirstName, Today is " + formatDate(), style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake I made in the formatting of the string. here is the correct way: "Hi ${user.firstName}, Today is "

Answer (score 0):

define a global variable to hold values which should be accessed by many classes, this will ensure any change on this value will be reflected across your app :

```
String userFirstName ;
class HomeMember extends StatelessWidget {

userFirstName = user.firstName;


}
```

Comment: I was able to fix it. It was a mistake I made in the formatting of the string. here is the correct way:   "Hi ${user.firstName}, Today is "

Comment: glad to hear this